# adding www to domain without reset it back to base

Tags: apache, redirect, http-status-code-301, no-www

Hi I am trying to do a redirect from non wwww to www  I am using the code below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^basedomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ www.basedomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

this works fine except it resets everything back to www.basedomain.com, so if had a link somwhere to go to basedomain.com/test.html and they cliked on the link, it would take them to www.basedomain.com and remove the test.html, how can I fix this so it keeps the url as it is and only appends www to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the "not the one i want to the one i want" approach instead:

```
RewriteBase /var/www/public_html/basedomain/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yoursite\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Edit, added in RewriteBase to help pathing issues on shared server.

Comment: thanks, but this now shows server rooth path in browser

Comment: When this happens, you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive.  try adding to the top, `RewriteBase /var/www/public_html/`

Comment: http://www.dev1.annastesting.com/bedding/bed-in-a-bag.html?Fdf sorry now its giving a 500 error

Comment: updated to include /basedomain/ at the end, try that.

Comment: If that doesn't work either, try just `RewriteBase /`

Comment: And what do you want to do with dev1 subdomain?   that's not what your question asked for.  dev1 will end up as www with this code.   www IS a subdomain

Comment: by adding RewriteBase /  it now still loses the struct and goes back t so this:
http://www.dev1.annastesting.com/window-1/window-hardware.html
redirects to this:
 http://www.dev1.annastesting.com/index.php

Comment: it should keep everything.. just add www. in front of it. thankls for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

the following should  take care of that

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^basedomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.basedomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: this didnt work, it now says www.basedomian.com/var/www/public_html/basedomain/index.php

Comment: what is the original URL you have tested ?

Comment: http://dev1.annastesting.com/ redirects to http://www.dev1.annastesting.com/

but dev1.annastesting.com/dining/glassware.html should go to www.dev1.annastesting.com/dining/glassware.html

Comment: can you post your entire mod-rewrite directives ?  I suspect something else further up is messing it up . The above directive should work. you could test by removing other directives above this one in the htaccess file.

Comment: can I email it to you?